# How can I reference a file in my custom module?

Tags: magento2, csv

I have a csv file in my custom module that I would like to open and parse in my Setup/InstallData file. 
The csv is located in MyModule/MyDirectory/files/.
When I try to reference the file using the relative path, ../../files/myfile.csv, I get the error:

[ErrorException]
  file(../../files/myfile.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

How can I get the file path of my csv so I can open it using open() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to implement something similar to 
\Magento\Framework\Module\Dir ->getDir('YourModule', 'files')
which is usually called by \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader ->getModuleDir(DIR_TYPE, 'moduleName').

```
// inject component registrar
private $componentRegistrar;
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrarInterface $componentRegistrar)
{
    $this->componentRegistrar = $componentRegistrar;
}

// custom getDir method
public function getDir($moduleName, $type = '')
{
    $path = $this->componentRegistrar->getPath(\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, $moduleName);

    if ($type) {
        $path .= '/' . $type;
    }

    return $path;
}

// usage ->getDir('YourModule', 'files')
```

**Update:** 
Note that built-in getDir() method only accepts the following folder types:
Dir::MODULE_ETC_DIR = 'etc'
Dir::MODULE_ETC_DIR = 'i18n'
Dir::MODULE_ETC_DIR = 'view'
Dir::MODULE_ETC_DIR = 'Controller'
That is why you have to write your own method to reach your 'files' folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used $importFile = realpath('./') . '/app/code/MyModule/Mydirectory/files/myfile.csv'; but your way looks better :)